# Replace string with other string python django

Tags: python, regex, django

Hi guys i want to convert link into proper format for example i have text like

```
This is google link https://www.google.com
This is gmail link https://www.gmail.com
```

And what i want is

```
This is google link <a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
This is gmail link <a href="https://www.gmail.com">https://www.gmail.com</a>
```

and here is code that i have written

```
body_without_quotes = request.POST.get('stripped-text', '')
data1 = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', body_without_quotes)
for da in data1:
    link = "<a href="+da+">"+da+"</a>"
    body_without_quotes = body_without_quotes.replace(da, link)
print body_without_quotes
```

but it does not print required output can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here.This is the output i am getting right now

```
This is gogle link <a href=<a href=https://www.google.com>>https://www.google.com></a>https://www.google.com</a>
This is gmail link <a href=https://www.gmail.com>https://www.gmail.com</a> <<a href=<a href=https://www.google.com>>https://www.google.com></a>https://www.google.com</a>>
```

Thanks

Comment: you mean you have a *foo.com* and you want to return it as *a* html a tag

Comment: yup you are right

Comment: What s the output that you are seeing?

Comment: ok its too easy *return "<a href='%s'>link</a>" % "your_link"

Comment: @mohammed qudah i have multiple links in one string so i can not simply return

Comment: @Hybrid it append in previous text mean to say duplicate the text and i see link two times with and without html tag

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev i have updated my question with output

Comment: The code in my answer works as expected, it you previous code with fixed variable. I use python 3.6. Are you sure `body_without_quotes = request.POST.get('stripped-text', '')` has correct data?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev have you got the same format as i mentioned above mean to say i have another solution for that but formatting is not correct in that solution like the whole text appears in one line etc.